# Checking if two NSDate instances contain the same date value

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift.
I've got one big ( just for me ) problem.
I have NSUserDefaults what I need to delete by the end of everyday.
I know that I need to compare dates for this, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use NSCalendar method isDate(inSameDayAsDate:), so we can create a NSDate extension that uses that method to return a boolean value:

```
extension NSDate {
    struct Calendar {
        static let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    }
    func isInSameDayAs(date date: NSDate) -> Bool {
        return Calendar.gregorian.isDate(self, inSameDayAsDate: date)
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let date1 = NSDate()
let date2 = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(60)

if date1.isInSameDayAs(date: date2 ){
    print("true")   // "true\n"
} else {
    print("false")
}
```

Comment: Leo, is it right that this code will do something only if app will work at this interval ( 60sec )? But what if user will close the app at 11 and open at 1?

Comment: @Егор Кузнецов 60 seconds was just to create a different date in the same day and of course if you try this at 11:59:0xpm if will give you 2 different days

Comment: You just need to save NSDate() to NSUserDefaults and next time the user opens the app all you need is to check if Now (NSDate()) it is not same day as the date saved. If it is not just delete it at that launch and save the new date

Comment: Thanks you, Leo, you saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

given two dates `dataA` and `dateB`

```
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var componantsA = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.MonthCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.YearCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.DayCalendarUnit, fromDate:dateA)
    var componantsB = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.MonthCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.YearCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.DayCalendarUnit, fromDate:dateB)

    var sameDay:Bool = (componantsA.day == componantsB.day) && (componantsA.month == componantsB.month) && (componantsA.year == componantsB.year)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, Moriya! It solved my problem! :)